# Jquery click doesn't add a style

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add a css style to body, if i click on menu with jquery, but it doesnt work.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cve5kt5/6/)

```
$("label").click(function() {
    $("body").css('background: red;');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assignment of the value is wrong. Try this:

```
$("label").click(function() {
    $("body").css("background", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can add a style in two ways using jquery :

```
$("body").css({'background:red'}); //for multiple property
```

or

```
$("body").css("background","red"); //for single property
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, for multiple styles you can do something like:

```
css({"propertyname":"value","propertyname":"value",...});
```

**Example:**

```
$("body").css({"background": "red"});
```